# How to get integer and string input using scanf?

Tags: arrays, c, string, string-comparison

I have a problem in C language

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char usrname[17] = "nsa-secret-agent";
    char password[9] = "marshal41";
    char usr[512], pass[512];

    printf("username: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", usr);
    printf("password: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", pass);
    printf("%s\n", usr);
    printf("%s\n", pass);

    if (strcmp(usrname, usr) == 0 && strcmp(password, pass) == 0){
        printf("You Have Successfully Logged In!\n");
    }

    else{
        printf("username or password not found!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it runs without any errors but when give input like below:

```
username: nsa-secret-agent
password: marshal41
nsa-secret-agent
marshal41
username or password not found!
```

I am giving correct credentials but still it's showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays for `usrname` and `password` are off by one:

```
char usrname[17] = "nsa-secret-agent";
char password[9] = "marshal41";
```

These are short one byte for the zero terminator which makes the comparison later fail. Either add one or just use

```
char usrname[] = "nsa-secret-agent";
char password[] = "marshal41";
```

or you could even use

```
char *usrname = "nsa-secret-agent";
char *password = "marshal41";
```

since the strings are not modified.